# "iBooks vs. Kindle in terms of number of textbooks for students" -- appropriate question?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

Is Superuser the appropriate site to ask about whether the Kindle or iBooks platform has more textbooks available and which platform offers a better experience (i.e., I've seen the Apple ads with the textbooks having all sorts of interactive capabilities, but not Kindle)?

Or, if I were a student, which is more suitable?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think its on-topic as it isn't even a comparison between two apps (that run on 'banned' products) but more a comparison between licensing deals. Its like asking to compare Hulu and Netflix, which really isn't the purpose of this site

Comment: But asking "Which platform has more textbooks available: iBooks or Kindle" would be on topic, correct?

Comment: I don't think so. The answer could change from day to day, and even if it doesn't, I don't see the value in simply reporting total numbers without the context of what kind of textbooks they are.

Comment: As @LordTorgamus said. Do you want to update the answer every second day to reflect the actual number?

Comment: I see how the answers to the question would quickly become obsolete. I'll refrain from asking. Thanks.

Comment: But why would this question be voted down in the Meta?

Comment: Try literature.stackexchange.com for Kindle and iBooks questions.

Comment: If your question is voted down on meta this means that people don't agree with you. This doesn't mean you posted a "wrong" question.

Comment: Ok thanks. This is my first or second meta question as you can probably tell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No** - the [FAQs](https://superuser.com/faq#questions) specifically state that **only** questions that are about

- **Computer hardware**
- **Computer software**

are allowed.

Furthermore, it also states that questions that are about "**electronic devices**, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they **interface with your computer**"

### The question you're asking has *absolutely* nothing to do with a computer (hardware or software)

Comment: interface with the computer. Got it. I should probably read the FAQs again.

Comment: I hate to ask, but can you please up-vote my answer?

Comment: there you go! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**No**

It is strongly bordering on a list, and won't have a conclusive answer ever. It's the same as asking if the App Store is better then Amazon, just with more flair and trying to hide behind a comparison of books.

Also, where is the computer hardware/software problem your trying to solve?

Comment: Hardware/software. Ok thank you, I didn't remember that.